# transaction fails when i use address[] memory

Tags: solidity, remix, bsc, solidity-0.8.x

i was practicing on BSC testnet and my solidity code is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
    function factory() external view returns (address);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function swap(uint256 amount0Out, uint256 amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
    function skim(address to) external;
    function sync() external;
}

contract getData{
    function getOrderedReserves(
        address[] memory pool
    )
        external
        view
        returns (
            uint256[] memory Reserves
        )
    {
        uint c=0;
        for(uint i=0;i<pool.length;i++)
        {
            (Reserves[c], Reserves[c+1], ) = IUniswapV2Pair(pool[i]).getReserves();
            c+=2;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I am using remix as an IDE and when i call `getOrderedReserves` my transaction will fail. But when i use same code without using array variables, it works. Please help

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: thanks bro. I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is i was trying to use the array varibale `reserves` without allocating space. so the new code that works for me is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
    function factory() external view returns (address);

    function token0() external view returns (address);

    function token1() external view returns (address);

    function getReserves()
        external
        view
        returns (
            uint112 reserve0,
            uint112 reserve1,
            uint32 blockTimestampLast
        );

    function swap(
        uint256 amount0Out,
        uint256 amount1Out,
        address to,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external;

    function skim(address to) external;

    function sync() external;
}

contract getData {
    function getOrderedReserves(address[] memory pool)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory Reserves)
    {
        uint256 length = pool.length;
        Reserves = new uint256[](length*2);
        uint256 c=0;
        for(uint256 i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            (Reserves[c], Reserves[c+1], ) = IUniswapV2Pair(pool[i]).getReserves();
            c+=2;
        }
        
    }
}
```